# .htaccess redirect only within certain folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have a few folders set up and use a basic rewrite for PHP extensions (where the URL does not display the .php) (e.g. /public_html/folderA | /public_html/folderB).

I've now set up some new folders that I do NOT want to have this redirect apply to (/public_html/folderC), but I can't figure out how to make the redirect apply exclusively to certain paths?

Comment: What did you try already?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a .htaccess file in public_html/folderC with:

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

You can also write exclusions (before other rules)

```
RewriteRule ^(public_html\/folderC)($|/) - [L]
```

Notice the [L], that will tell the rewrite engine not to look for any other rules.